# Two recv() threads, non-blocking, same socket: do both receive a sent buffer?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, winsock, recv

The title says it all, but here's a more in-depth explanation:
I made a chat server for some of my friends and I, but one of the last issues I need to iron out is that when one of them disconnects, there's no available indication of this to the others connected to the server. I'm planning to start a separate thread that makes sure some specific data is sent to the server every minute or so (sending of data also automated on the client side) to keep each client in-check. If one were to not send data for a certain amount of time, it would be discarded as "disconnected."
The problem is, the way my program is set up, it would be impossible to discern whether they both were receiving data without dismantling most of the code already there.

Help is greatly appreciated,
~P

Comment: If your goal is to implement a heartbeat/keepalive on a socket, you don't need to use a second thread to do so; just use the timeout feature of select() or poll() or etc to wake up your original thread when it's time to send something.

Comment: It's actually better with one thread - there is no need to send a keep-alive poll message if you have just received data - Rx data should restart the timeout.

Comment: Wow, Martin... I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much everyone! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Two recv() threads, non-blocking, same socket: do both receive a sent buffer?

No, but they would both receive the EOS indication (return value is zero).

Comment: Ah. Well then it looks like I'll have to find another way to check for disconnection...

Thanks. :)

Comment: It's hard to see what the underlying problem is here. You just have to keep track of which clients are disconnecting and notify all relevant parts of your application.